# Creating a turn based game and how do I get the values to actually subtract? I keep getting 100 back everytime I attack?

Tags: c++

"Creating a turn based game, here is my code- it runs but every time you attack it still gives back 100 for the hit points, am I stuck in the loop? I keep trying to fix it but I can not seem to be able to figure out why it keeps coming back the same.  Do I need a break soome where? Thanks!"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int batmanHPcurrent; //current HP of player1
int killercrocHPcurrent; // current HP of monster
int plaHP[]; //player1 hp sequence
int monHP[]; //monster hp sequence
char playerAction;

void removeHP(int i)
{
    i = i + 10;
}
void addHP(int i)
{
    if (i > 80)
    {
        i = 100;
    }
    else
    {
        i = i + 20;
    }
}
int main()
{
    batmanHPcurrent = 100;
    killercrocHPcurrent = 100;
    cout << "Killer Croc appears and challenges you to battle!" << endl;
    system("pause");

     while (batmanHPcurrent > 0 && killercrocHPcurrent > 0)
    {
        cout << "(A) Attack Killer Croc" << endl << "(H) Use this       (heal  spell) if injured" << endl;
        cin >> playerAction;
        if (playerAction == 'A')
        {
            cout << "Batman attacks and deals 10 damage to Killer Croc." << endl;
            removeHP(killercrocHPcurrent);

        }
        if (playerAction == 'H')
        {
            cout << "healing potion administered. 20 HP restored." << endl;
            addHP(batmanHPcurrent);

    }
    cout << "Killer Croc! You take 10 damage." << endl;
    removeHP(batmanHPcurrent);
    cout << "Batman currently has " << batmanHPcurrent << " HP." << endl;
    cout << "Killer Croc currently has " << killercrocHPcurrent << " HP." << endl;
}
if (batmanHPcurrent < 1)
{
    batmanHPcurrent = 100;
    cout << "Death and darkness is all you see." << endl;
    system("pause");
}

if (killercrocHPcurrent < 1)
{
    killercrocHPcurrent = 150;
    cout << "You are now the champion!!" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: In `removeHP` you should subtract 10. Currently, it's adding 10. This won't fix your problem (Anton Afanasjew's answer will) but will cause a separate problem of healing whomever it's called on. Also, `i = i + 20` can be written as `i += 20;` Similarly with `-`.

Comment: a general suggestion: Dont write a wall of code just to realize in the end that there is a bug somewhere. Instead write small pieces and test them before using them in the full program.

Comment: The problem here is that Batman cannot deal less than 100 damage because... You know... He is Batman!! :D

Comment: `addHP` and `removeHP` take *a copy* of `i`, and their changes to `i` are not visible outside of the function. Instead pass `i` by reference or `return i` and assign the value.

Answer (score 2):

In your function removeHP you are not actually changing the variable batmanHPcurrent. Google "parameter by value" and "parameter by reference"